# What constitutes a circle of fifths progression?

Tags: theory, chord-progressions

Is a circle of fifths that goes backward (eg. D G C F Bb) still considered a circle of fifths progression?

Comment: Whether it is written clockwise or anticlockwise it can be read either way. Circle (cycle?) of fifths and fourths.

Answer (score 11):

Typically, a circle-of-fifths progression is a progression that moves by *descending* fifths. Thus, your progression is a standard circle-of-fifths progression!

The reason descending fifths are so common is due to the dominant-to-tonic relationship between two adjacent chords. In your example of `D G C F`, `D` is the dominant to `G`, `G` is then the dominant to `C`, `C` is then the dominant to `F`, and so on. One of the many reasons this dominant-to-tonic relationship is so convincing is that each chord contains the leading tone of the next chord. `G` contains the leading tone to `C` (`B`), `C` contains the leading tone to `F` (`E`), etc.

Ascending fifths are much harder to pull off convincingly because it lacks this dominant-to-tonic relationship, and consequently each chord lacks the leading tone of the next chord.

However, in the ascending-fifths progression, each chord has the leading tone of the chord *before* it! So if any fifth progression is "backwards," it is the ascending one.

Comment: Also, technically, descending fifths and ascending fifths are sequences, not progressions.

Comment: Hey Joe managed the backwards sequence well !

Comment: @JohnWu It depends on who you ask, I think. "Sequence" and "progression" are some of those terms that mean slightly different things to everyone. My training has always been that "sequence" indicates a repeating harmonic *and melodic* pattern, which is why I chose not to use that term in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The circle of fifths progression is I - IV - VII - III - VI - II - V - I.

The circle of fifths progression is commonly a succession through the seven diatonic chords of a diatonic scale by fifths downwards, including one progression by diminished fifth, (in C: between F and B) and one diminished chord (in C major, Bdim), returning at the end to the tonic.

In major keys, it will be I - IV - vii° - iii - vi - ii - V - I.  In C major, it will be: C - F - Bdim - Em - Am - Dm - G - C.

In minor keys, it will be i - iv - VII - III - VI - ii° - V - i.  In A minor, it will be: Am - Dm - G - C - F - Bdim - E - Am.

Answer (score 0):

> Is a circle of fifths that goes backward (eg. D G C F Bb) still considered a circle of fifths progression?

The point is:

**The circle of fifths IS going *BACKWARD!***

The symbolic representation of the circle like a clock is only accidentally, respectively to read it clockwisely has been  your decision.